# How do you drop certain rows per group pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe and would like to drop certain rows for each category. Here is the data:

```
data={'GROUP':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'],'DATE':['202101','202102','202103','201907','201908','201909',
'201910','202003','202004','202005','202006','202007']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['GROUP','DATE'])
```

```
   GROUP    DATE
0      A  202101
1      A  202102
2      A  202103
3      B  201907
4      B  201908
5      B  201909
6      B  201910
7      C  202003
8      C  202004
9      C  202005
10     C  202006
11     C  202007
```

I would like to drop all the rows after the second date per group. In other words I would like to produce something to this effect:

```
  GROUP    DATE
0     A  202101
1     A  202102
3     B  201907
4     B  201908
7     C  202003
8     C  202004
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df.groupby('GROUP').head(2)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  GROUP    DATE
0     A  202101
1     A  202102
3     B  201907
4     B  201908
7     C  202003
8     C  202004
```

Answer (score 0):

Group the dataframe by `GROUP` and apply a function to take a slice of two values only.

```py
>>> df.groupby(['GROUP'])['DATE'].apply(lambda x: x[:2]).droplevel(-1).reset_index()

  GROUP    DATE
0     A  202101
1     A  202102
2     B  201907
3     B  201908
4     C  202003
5     C  202004
```